# Show Taxonomy Terms that have been tagged on any piece of content

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type and it allows for one taxonomy term to be tagged to it.

I want to show that term on each nodes page. How can I do this with views Please?

Answer (score 0):

With views, you can create a view of content with type filter of your specific content type.
And then select format as fields

[image]

Then add the term reference field which saved the taxonomy term for nodes.

After that in Advanced settings, you will need to add contextual filter of node id. with default value to take from the URL.

[image]
[image]

You can make this view as a block and then assign this block on node pages.